# Recursively replace all links with actual files (gnu)

Tags: scripting, symlink, gnu

In order to run Code dx on Linux files, I need to replace all links with the actual files. Haven't worked in Linux in years and am getting confused by terminology. Been searching for answers for two days. Is there a simple script for this? I have 25 million lines of code.

Original dir:
afile
bfile
clink_to_cfile_in_another_dir (possible traversing several links)

Desired end result:
afile
bfile
cfile

I have gotten this far, but it doesn't quite work:

```
find . -type l -exec "echo 'replacing {}'; cp -LR '{}' '{}'.deref rm '{}' \;"
```

Comment: I have gotten this far:

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues

- The `\;` needs to be outside the quotes, it is a separate argument to exec
- You are missing a `;` before the final rm command
- exec will try and run the whole command as one single command.

To run multiple commands like this you can exec a shell and pass your script to it

```
find . -type l -exec /bin/bash -c "echo 'replacing {}'; cp -LR '{}' '{}.deref' ; rm '{}'" \;
```

seems to work.